# Index 1, size 1 Exception

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I looked all the questions about this exception. I know that array index begins 0 and if the size is 1, we could only access the index 0. Although I know this logic, I could not fix the following code.

```
  private static Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> executions = new HashMap<String, Map<String, List<String>>>();

public static String readExecution(String jobName, String deviceName, int executionNumber) {
    String result = null;
    Map<String, List<String>> jobExecutions = executions.get(jobName);
    if (jobExecutions != null) {
      List<String> executionPerDevice = jobExecutions.get(deviceName);
      result = executionPerDevice.get(executionNumber); // ERROR
    }

    return result;
  }
```

EDIT:
The answer of Fildor's comment.execution number is 1.

[image]
Any help?
Thank you.

Comment: Debug it. I'd say `executionNumber` is "1". If you start numbering executions with 1, then make this `result = executionPerDevice.get(executionNumber-1);` And I would also do some nullchecks.

Comment: can you check size of executionPerDevice  and compare it with executionNumber.

Comment: IndexOutOfBound exception is an extremely easy exception. You're trying to get something that does not exist. Just debug your code to figure out why there is no value when you're fetching it.

Comment: What happens if `deviceName` is not in jobExecutions? (Retorical Question)

Comment: @Fildor please look my edit

Comment: There you have it. So you are in fact trying to execute `executionPerDevice.get(1)` while its size is 1. You already stated you **know** that this is wrong. Index should be 0. See my first comment.

Comment: @Fildor result = executionPerDevice.get(executionNumber-1); did not solve my problem still I get the same exception error.

Comment: Can you please add the stacktrace? If executionPerDevice has size 1 and executionNumber is 1 then, executionNumber-1 is 0 which should be in bounds. Did you recompile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick Solution:
The execution number is passed externally as an argument, so you should check if this number fits with the executionPerDevice size anyway:

```
      if (executionPerDevice.size() >= executionNumber){
            result = executionPerDevice.get(executionNumber);
        }
```

Comment: @NicolasFilotto still I am newbie could you please explain why you found this condition false

Comment: because the index in a List goes from 0 to size -1 included, here the test is incorrect as you could have executionNumber == size which would lead to an IndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 0):

These runtime exception message tend to tell you **everything** you need to know in order to understand the issue.

SIZE is ONE

INDEX is ONE.

Consider the set of valid indices for a list of size one.